# display text instead of icon on mouseover - React material ui button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material ui button in my project. Initially the add button is having only **+ icon**.

When the mouse is hovered I need to change the content of button from the icon to the text "CREATE ITEM"

The code is as follows.

```
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  iconHover: {
    '&:hover': {
      border: '2px solid green',
      //TODO display the text CREATE ITEM instead of AddIcon
    }
  },

  floatBtn: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
  },
}));



const Index = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return(
  <div className={classes.floatBtn}>
    <Fab size="small" color="secondary" aria-label="add" className={classes.iconHover}>
          <AddIcon />
        </Fab>
  </div>
)};
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: You can have an eventlistener on the div - when mouseenter, display text, and when mouseleave display icon

Comment: is there a css way to achieve this? something like &:after

Comment: Not if you wanna use React Material UI

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can use `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` :

```
const Index = () => {
  const [hover,sethover]=useState(false);
  const classes = useStyles();
  return(
  <div className={classes.floatBtn}>
    <Fab onMouseOver={()=>sethover(true)} 
     onMouseOut={()=>sethover(false)} 
     size="small" color="secondary" aria-label="add" 
     className={classes.iconHover}>
          {hover?:("some text"):(<AddIcon />)
        </Fab>
  </div>
)};
```

Comment: onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave worked better for me, but that's a great tip. Thanks!