# Display text when hover on icon ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am new to react and want to display a text when the user hover over the icon. I am using material-ui and Reactjs  latest version. this the last code that I tried

```
    return (
    <List className={classes.list}>
        {items.map((item, index, list) => (
            <Fragment key={item.id}>
                    <ListItemText primary={item.name} secondary={item.uniqueId}/>
                    <LensIcon style={{color: changeColorStatus(item)}}--this part is not working 
                              onMouseOver={() => setShowTextStatu(true)}
                              onMouseOut={() => setShowTextStatu(false)}
                              {showTextStatus?("Status"): ""}/>-- 
                </ListItem>
                {index < list.length - 1 ? <Divider/> : null}
            </Fragment>
        ))}
    </List>
);}
```

this the styles

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
list: {
    maxHeight: '100%',
    overflow: 'auto',
},
icon: {
    width: '25px',
    height: '25px',
    filter: 'brightness(0) invert(1)',
},
hover: {
    border: '2px solid green'
}}));
```

I tried these solutions but none worked with me:

[Show and Hide Something When Hovering Over Another Element](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/react-onhover-event-handling-with-examples)

[Display text instead of icon on mouseover - React material ui button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58975228/display-text-instead-of-icon-on-mouseover-react-material-ui-button)

[How to add onMouseEnter or onMouseOver in ReactJS](https://linguinecode.com/post/how-to-add-onmouseenter-or-onmouseover-in-reactjs)

Comment: did you find a solution, in a similar situation

Comment: Hi @Sam no , I have change the idea

Answer (score 2):

Material-UI has a built-in tooltips function that show text on hover.
https://mui.com/components/tooltips/